# Hash and backbone router

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

How should I make this using Router?

```
var itemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

     events: {
         'click #loadPage': 'loadPage'
     },

     loadPage: function () {
         document.location.hash = '#tasks/' + this.model.get('id');
     }

});
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to make the same thing using router.navigate. Or maybe is useless because Backbone.History record it doing my way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-114), router.navigate is simply proxying to Backbone.history, which is global so you should be able to use it without problems:

```
Backbone.history.navigate("#tasks/", { trigger: true })
```

the `{trigger: true}` options as expected will trigger the hash change so that your router can react if it has that route registered.

Answer (score 0):

You must have "global" variable with a Router instance.

Then just call that variable in this way:

```
// yourRouter was defined in your main controller like this: 
// var YourRouterClass = Backbone.Router.extend({ 
// stuff of your own Router
// });
// var yourRouter = new YourRouterClass(); <- this is your global router instance
yourRouter.navigate('tasks/'+this.model.get('id'), {trigger : true});
```